# Put Component on the right side

Tags: html, css, angular

how to arrange icon inside mat tree node always on the right side.

i share [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxbkby?file=src/app/tree-flat-overview-example.css) link from the angular example.

The goal what i want to achice is to have "add" icon stay always on the right side.
I add some css styling but nothing happend and i tried also with div but cannot work also.

any suggestion for my problem?

thanks.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxbkby-3supwe?file=src/app/tree-flat-overview-example.html

Comment: Thanks its works like i  want it...i had the properties before like justify-content: flex-end; but i put in another tag not in icon tag... thanks again.